# Hook into assert.* functions

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, assert

Background: I have a collection of functions that are used inside a template engine, where their output is *always* cast to strings. This means that when testing them, what I'm *really* interested in is their string representation.

Is there any way to “hook” into `assert.*()` to modify the input before each assertion?

That would save me from explicitly casting the output each time:

```
  it("should foo bar", () => {
    assert.strictEqual("" + myFunction1(foo), "bar")
    assert.strictEqual("" + myFunction1(baz), "fiz")
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering assert functions isn't a great idea because any other call to `assert.strictEqual` will *lie* to you, producing unexpected output. E.g. `assert.strictEqual(true, true)` will return `false` because `""+true` is not equal to `true`.

A better alternative is to use a utility function to proxy all your `assert.strictEqual` calls:

```
function assertWithCast (val1, val2) {
    assert.strictEqual("" + val1, val2)
}
```

Then use it in your tests:

```
it("should foo bar", () => {
  assertWithCast(myFunction1(foo), "bar")
  assertWithCast(myFunction1(baz), "fiz")
})
```